# Get a list of all used tables in a Postgresql SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, delphi, lazarus

Is there a way to get all the tables used in complex SELECT query in Postgesql without using an actual SQL parser?  ver. 9.5 and above will be used.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? For simple joins the JDBC driver will return that information through `ResultSetMetaData.getTableName(int)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
create or replace function get_query_tables(p_query text) returns text[] language plpgsql as $$
declare
  x xml;
begin
  execute 'explain (format xml) ' || p_query into x;
  return xpath('//explain:Relation-Name/text()', x, array[array['explain', 'http://www.postgresql.org/2009/explain']])::text[];
end $$;

select get_query_tables('your query here');
```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6d89e764e46d665ded101f797797be7a)

Answer (score -2):

```
TableList:=TStringList.Create; 
pgConnection1.GetTableNames(TableList,False);
```

Comment: Q not about all tables in the DB but about tables involved in the query.

Comment: Yes OK, I should read the question more carefully. Much more complex that I thought. Just trying to contribute when I get a chance.

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) answer the question, you should add an explanation stating why/how it solves the problem.