# List of tables/columns touched during SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

With postgres, is there a means of determining what tables/columns will be touched given an SQL query? I am attempting to see if given an SQL query, the user (a student) attempted to return data from a particular set of tables.

I want to do this programmatically such that having a human review the code is not necessary. I am also trying to avoid situations where invalid input might pass simple string search checks, for example having all the table names within a comment.

Comment: your SQL query will have all the tables/views, unless its calling a function, which might be calling different tables

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you have the query that they used, couldn't you just... read it?  And if your ultimate goal is to restrict access to certain tables for student users, you could just revoke their read access to those tables

Comment: I have updated the question to be a bit more specific as to the situation.

Comment: For tables: [Get a list of all used tables in a Postgresql SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44811746/593144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so solely through Postgres, [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html) should help you here. `EXPLAIN` will show tables accessed by a given query, with some details on columns/indexes used as well.

You could adapt this problem into one that works with string matching however. By simply parsing off any comment sections on a given query you should be able to fairly reliably string search for any columns/tables you want to know about.

Comment: This was initially what I thought would have to be the solution, I am glad to hear it come from someone else as well. It still involves string searching, but at least it is against output generated by the sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Explain operator to give you an idea of the calculations and index searches the database has done in the background.

Check this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html

PostgreSQL devises a query plan for each query it receives. Choosing the right plan to match the query structure and the properties of the data is absolutely critical for good performance, so the system includes a complex planner that tries to choose good plans. You can use the EXPLAIN command to see what query plan the planner creates for any query.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tenk1;

                     QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on tenk1  (cost=0.00..458.00 rows=10000 width=244)
```